# How do I add Kartik ActiveField on Kartik DetailView?

Tags: yii2

I'm using Kartik's awesome extension called DetailView.  I'd like to add the Kartik widget called ActiveField to the DetailView.  What is the proper way to use the ActiveField widget in the DetailView widget?

The code I'm using generates the error `First parameter must either be an object or the name of an existing class`.  According to Kartik's [documentation](http://demos.krajee.com/detail-view), any widget (not just the DetailView widgets) can be used.  What is the proper way to do that?

```
$attributes = [
    ['attribute' => 'definition_summary',
     'format' => 'raw',
     'type'=>DetailView::INPUT_WIDGET,
     'widgetOptions'=>[
         'class'=>ActiveField::className(),
         'addon' => ['prepend' => ['content' => '@']],
    ],
];
echo DetailView::widget([
   'model' => $model,
   'attributes' => $attributes,
]);
```

Comment: Refer input and widget section. [Kartik detail view](http://demos.krajee.com/detail-view)

Comment: show the code of $attributes before you perfomr the array_merge